# infinite loop while using useEffect and redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component which renders tabs based on an array in redux store and also updates the store based on the user click on tab. But it is causing infinite loop when I click the tab.

```
function TabsList() {
  const reportNamesStore = useSelector(getStoreTabs);
  const [reportNames, setReportNames] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
            dispatch(tabClicked({ active: index }))
            setReportNames([...reportNamesStore]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setReportNames([...reportNamesStore]);
  }, [reportNamesStore]);

  return (
       ...
      <a onClick={() => handleClick(index)}/>
   )
 
enter code here
```

And my reducer is as below

```
getTabsReducer(
   state = { active: -1, tabs: [] },
  ...
case TAB_CLICKED:
  return {
    tabs: [...state],
    active: action.payload.active,
  };
```

Comment: set ReportNames in handlClick  triggers the useEffect because it's a dependeny that changed? Did you tried it without `useEffect`?

Comment: first thing you should ask yourself is if you need it in both redux and local? otherwise you can just remove `reportNames` and work off `reportNamesStore`

Comment: also `tabs: [...state],` should be `tabs: [...state.tabs],`

Comment: Your `TAB_CLICKED` return should just be `{ ...state, active: action.payload.active }`, you don't want to spread state into sub-state.